# Wordpress Uploaded Images Show Broken Link

Tags: wordpress

I can upload images via the WP Photo Seller Plugin, but all the links to the images show as broken.  Anyone know what I can change to get them to show?  I checked the folder permissions and they seem to be fine.

Here is a link: 
http://pics.teamdance.com/photogallery/gallery67/

Comment: For some reason if you try view the images they redirect to `http://127.0.0.1/`, can you double check that the images are saved in the `wp-content/uploads/wp_photo_seller/67/` folder?

Comment: Yes I just checked and they seem to all be there

Comment: [This](http://pics.teamdance.com/wp-content/uploads/wp_photo_seller/67/watermark_IMG_0133.jpg) is a link to one of the images. Can you see that image or does it redirect you to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: It redirects me to 127.0.0.1  This all worked before when I had it on a Bluehost cpanel server and then I moved it to my own server with zpanel and its not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out the permissions on the server were off.   A quick chmod solved the problem.